# :before content in HTML drop down <option> not working

Tags: html, css, select

I want to show the color dot before the label of the option, something like this:

[image]

Here is my code, I have put the `:before` CSS attribute to show the dot but it is not working! I'm not sure why it is not working, any help would be appreciated. Please do let me know if there is an alternative to achieve the output.

```css
option:before, h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<select name="Folders Color">
  <option>Yellow</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<h1>Here it works in H1!</h1>
```

Comment: You can only have text as children of an option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: Oh okay, but how do I make something like the attached screenshot in the question?

Comment: use a plugin so you can create a styled dropdown - this is the one I usually use: https://select2.org/